# Why do i get an error while opening a link through selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

i am having trouble using selenium to open a chrome link

```
from selenium import webdriver
url=r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
drvier=webdriver.Chrome(url)
driver.get("https://us02web.zoom.us/meeting/attendee")) #a zoom link, hidden by me
```

The error was:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lavni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\CHEM.py", line 3, in <module>
    drvier=webdriver.Chrome(url)
  File "C:\Users\lavni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\lavni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "C:\Users\lavni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 109, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 0
```

Comment: Shouldn't the argument to webdriver.Chrome(...) be the path to chromedriver.exe and not to chrome.exe? See https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not about the link. You trying to open the normal chrome with selenium, you need a ChromeDriver which can be controlled with selenium. You can download the ChromeDriver from [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/).

Make sure that the ChromeDriver and installed Chrome versions match.

Comment: upon running through the package,it says that chromedriver has started successfully.yet it still doesnt work

Comment: Can you post the traceback if there is an error with the ChromeDriver too, if there is no error can you explain exactly what is happening?

Comment: okay,nevermind, i realised that i copied the wrong path.

Answer (score 0):

Your driver is declared without "i" (drver), and after that, you are refering it as driver.

The link opens ok directly on browser?